# Is it possible to run a Visual Foxpro application on Delphi Honeywell 6100 mobile computer

Tags: visual-foxpro

I just purchased a Honeywell 6100 mobile computer. I have an application software developed in Visual Foxpro 6.0 and installed running on Windows 2008 R2 server, using flat files.

Would like to access Product database using Honeywell 6100 mobile computer(connected to the office Wifi and have access to office network),  to read the barcode from the showroom product and display one line of Description, 2nd line packing detail, 3rd line price and stores in a text file or dbf file & save it on the windows 2008 server in a specific folder.

Let which will be used in the VFP 6.0 applications running on the server to generate the quotation based on the barcode selected and saved in the text/dbf file.

Comment: It seems you have posted your question in wrong section. Stack owerflow is intended for software developers to discus their problem inpmelenting certain features into their programs. And Delphi is a programming language used for software development. So if your question is indeed programmin oriented I belive that using of Visual-FoxPro tag would be more suitable. And remove Delphi tag unless you are talking about some software developed with Delphi programming language.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't run Visual FoxPro on the Honeywell 6100, because it runs Windows CE.

The simplest way to do this is to periodically upload a CSV file containing product and price information to the Honeywell and periodically download a file containing order information from the Honeywell.

You then have your Visual FoxPro application on the server process the orders. You also need some software on the handheld to handle creating orders.